# Base computation via Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight

Is there a combination of math functions I could use in spotlight to accomplish change of base ? I know I can do it on a case by case basis with normal algebra.

Comment: I wish there could be a way to map some abbreviations to the Programmer's mode of the Calculator.app (I guess that is beyond lazy)

Answer (score 4):

The algebraic way to do it is log<sub>b</sub>x=log<sub>a</sub>x/log<sub>a</sub>b. In spotlight, the log(x) function is log<sub>10</sub>x and the ln(x) function is log<sub>e</sub>x. So taking log<sub>b</sub>x would be log(x)/log(b). However, rounding is significant enough to have the answer off even if it should be a whole number. For example, I tested log(4)/log(2) and got 1.9999999997 when it should be exactly 2.

Comment: As it is a floating point calculation the result won't be exactly 2. There will always be errors. (Although that error is more than I would expect I would expect accuracy to 14-15 significant figures)

Comment: @Mark Yes, I expected it to be more precise too, that is why I added that example. The calculator application is precise enough that it returns 2.